# Cannot type backslash in Sublime Text on Linux with international Mac keyboard

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

When I use Sublime Text in my Mac OS, forward slash `/` is typed with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> and backslash `\` is typed with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>. This works perfectly and the same in all Mac apps.

However, I'm also using Sublime Text in a Linux Virtual Machine running on said Mac and there I cannot type `\` with <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> - nothing happens. **EDIT:** If I enable input and command logging in the Sublime Text console (`sublime.log_input(True)` and `sublime.log_commands(True)`) I see that <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> is actually emitting the `auto_complete` command that is bound to <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> in the default keyboard binding settings file for Linux.

I also cannot type left brace `{` or right brace `}` in the Linux VM using the Mac combinations <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>8</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>.

Any ideas how to remedy this? **EDIT:** For example, how can I *unbind* the default Linux key binding that emits `auto_complete` for <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>7</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved this by adding these overrides to my User keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["shift+alt+7"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\\"} },
{ "keys": ["shift+alt+8"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "{"} },
{ "keys": ["shift+alt+9"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "}"} },
```

Comment: I have this problem for all `shift+alt+X` characters, because I need them to output the relevant characters and not be grabbed by ST3. (Here ST3 is in the wrong: Alt is used to insert characters on OS X, like AltGr on Windows, not to issue commands. That's what Cmd and Ctrl are for.) Do I have to duplicate half my keyboard layout in my User keymap? Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: I had a similar problem where I could not type a `/` after a `<` and doing this fixed it.  It sure made closing my HTML tags a real pain!

Answer (score 1):

The key combination of **SHIFT** and **ALT** key will overriding by your virtual machine...  which virtual machine you use.. .. check the virtual machine settings for **HOME** key.. and change it to something else in convenient way....

**EDIT** : In case VM is not the culprit.

You could unbind your default key settings using **unbound** command even though it is not offical..

Open the Following file

```
~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-keymap
```

or you can open it in your Sublime Text using

```
Preferences->Key Bindings-Default
```

In the file make the content look like

```
[
    {"keys":["shift+alt+7"], "command": "unbound" },
    {"keys":["shift+alt+8"], "command": "unbound" },
    {"keys":["shift+alt+9"], "command": "unbound" }
]
```

And save the file.

And also i recommend to redefine the commands bounded with these key in way that fit your needs.

Note: you can use any keyword instead of **unbound** . But make sure that the are not valid commands in Sublime Text (It is recommended to use **unbound** because up to sublime Text 3 **unbound** is not a command ).

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's overridden by the VM. If I enable input and command logging in the Sublime Text console (`sublime.log_input(True)` and `sublime.log_commands(True)`) I see that `shift-alt-7`, `shift-alt-8` and `shift-alt-9` are actually going through to the editor.

Comment: Unbinding only results in _nothing_ being emitted by those key bindings. They needed to actually be _rebound_ to the wanted output.

Comment: Doesn't work. As @JohannGerell says, unbinding them makes them output nothing.